# Overload operator-> for STL iterator

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator, g++

I'm writing my own implementation of the C++ STL map container. Now I'm trying to implement the iterator. It should allow you to do something like iter->first and iter->second that returns the key/value respectively and where iter is an object not a pointer. I'm wondering how I should overload this? It's a bit confusing because I'm not sure what the return type should be; it has to be an object with members first/second I suppose. Is it typical to return a reference to a wrapper/interface object or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value_type of a standard map is `std::pair<const KeyType, MappedType>`.

To achieve normal pointer semantics, `operator*` returns a reference, whereas `operator->` returns a pointer.

```
//minimal example
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>

struct It
{
  std::pair<const int, int> pair;
  std::pair<const int, int>* operator->() { return &pair; }
  std::pair<const int, int>& operator*() { return pair; }
};

int main()
{
  It it = {std::make_pair(10, 20) };
  (*it).second = 30;
  std::printf("%d %d\n", it->first, it->second);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you really mean the C++ standard library, then the `value_type` of a `map` is a `pair`. A pair has members `first` and `second`. Dereferencing an iterator in a `map` gives you a `pair`.

Comment: Even if the questioner really means the STL, the `value_type` of a `map` is still a `pair` ;-p

Comment: @SteveJessop: I can't speak to that, but if that's the case, then great!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you'll need a proxy to hold the relevant reference.

As for the type: standard-library iterators typically dereference to something of type `value_type`. For `map<K,V>`, the value type is `std::pair<K, V>` (or rather, `pair<key_type, mapped_type>`), which is where you get the `first`/`second` interface from.

(One of Stephan Lavavej's lectures explains how the MSVC++ implementation uses the same underlying data structure for `set` and `map`; the only difference is that `set::value_type` equals `set::key_type`, while `map::value_type` is `pair<key_type, mapped_type>`. That way you can tell the two apart with a simple trait check, but the iterator interface is virtually identical.)

Answer (score 2):

`std::map<K,V>::iterator` iterates over objects of type `std::pair<K,V>`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes. You should return a proxy-object or a reference to a proxy-object to get that behavior.